Prove associative property for summability over uncountable sets
When studying mathematical analysis independently from an italian text (Analisi 2/1, G. De Marco), I stumbled across the associative property for the summability over uncountable sets.
Let $S$ be the disjoint union of a family $\left\{S_\lambda \right\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda }$ of sets, i.e. $\left\{S_\lambda \right\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda }$ are not necessarily disjoint, and the disjoint union is defined here as $S=\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} S_{\lambda} \times \left\{ \lambda \right\}$.
Let $f: S \rightarrow K$ be a function over $S$, where $K$ is a field ($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).
$f$ is said to be summable over $S$ with sum $a\in K$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ it exists a finite subset  $F_{\varepsilon }$ of $S$ such that $\left| \sum_{x\in F}f(x) - a \right| < \varepsilon $ for every finite subset $F$ of $S$ containing $F_{\varepsilon }$.
Other facts that are known (already proved):

$f$ is summable over $S$ if and only if the restriction of $f$ over $S_{\lambda }$ is summable over $S_{\lambda }$ for every $\lambda \in \Lambda $;  (statement is false, see comments)
$f$ is summable over $S$ if and only if $\left|f \right|$ is summable over $S$;
if $f$ and $g$ are summable over $S$, also $f+g$ is summable over $S$;
if $k \in K$ and $f$ is summable over $S$, then $kf$ is summable over $S$;
if $f$ is a real-valued positive function, it is summable over $S$ if and only if $sup\left\{\sum_{x\in F}f(x) : F \subseteq S, F finite \right\}$ is finite, and $ \sum_{x\in S}f(x) = sup\left\{\sum_{x\in F}f(x) : F \subseteq  S, F finite \right\}$.

Edit: From now on it is assumed that $f$ is summable over $S$ and that the restriction of $f$ over $S_{\lambda }$ is summable over $S_{\lambda }$ for every $\lambda \in \Lambda $.
Using the previous facts I proved the associative property for $\left| f \right|$, that is, if $\mu (\lambda ) \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} \sum_{x\in S_{\lambda }}\left|f(x) \right|$, then $\sum_{x\in S}\left|f(x) \right| = \sum_{\lambda  \in \Lambda}\mu (\lambda)$ (proved by obtaining $\sum_{x\in S}\left|f(x) \right| \leq \sum_{\lambda  \in \Lambda}\mu (\lambda)$ and $\sum_{x\in S}\left|f(x) \right| \geq \sum_{\lambda  \in \Lambda}\mu (\lambda)$, relying heavily on fact (5) since $\left| f \right| \geq 0$, which I cannot for $f$).
If $\gamma(\lambda) \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} \sum_{x\in S_{\lambda }}f(x)$, how can I use the previous results to show that this associative property is valid not only for $\left|f \right|$ but also for $f$: $\sum_{x\in S}f(x)= \sum_{\lambda  \in \Lambda}\gamma  (\lambda)$ ?

Your fact 1 doesn't look right: take $\Lambda = \Bbb{N}$, $S_\lambda = {\lambda}$ and $f(\lambda) = \lambda$. Then the restrictions $f \mid S_\lambda$ are summable over $S_\lambda$ for any $\lambda$ (because $S_\lambda$ is finite). But $f$ is not summable over the union $S = \Bbb{N}$ of the $S_\lambda$. [PS: it would also be very helpful to tell us what you mean by the "associative property". You also seem to ve confused about whether or not the $S_\lambda$ are disjoint.]

Valid point, but about the PS, I think we take the "external" disjoint union here. So the $S_i$ can be non-disjoint, but their images in $S$ are disjoint. At least, this is how one can make sense of the 1st sentence in the 2nd paragraph.

Thanks for your response. (1) is false as RobArthan suggested, I found an error in my proof. The disjoint union is defined here as $S=\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} S_{\lambda} \times \left{ \lambda \right}$, I believe what
Martin Brandenburg was suggesting (please correct me if I'm not interpreting correctly). I edited the question with these corrections, and also added the assumptions that $f$ is summable over $S$ and that the restriction of $f$ over $S_{\lambda }$ is summable over $S_{\lambda }$ for every $\lambda \in \Lambda $. I hope to have made the question clearer now.
